# ¿Es posible distribuir mi apk sin Play Store y que no salte Google play protect?

Tags: google-play, expo

Esa es la cuestión, cuando ejecuto `expo build:android` me crea un apk que puedo descargar e instalar. Funciona perfectamente pero claro me salta Google Play Protect. Es una aplicación privada por lo que no quiero ponerla en Play Store... busco información y es que todo el mundo lo sube a Play Store, ¿Que puedo hacer? Gracias.

Comment: Podrias subirla a Appcenter y distribuirla de forma privada.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, he visto tu comentario y me he puesto a ello, lo acabo de probar, me sucede lo mismo... salta Google Play Protect, para hacer el apk uso las claves que me crea expo por defecto, ¿puede que sea eso?

Comment: y la app la firmas?